# Use Gimp Image Filter to create Cartoon Image

Tags: php, python, gimp

I want to create a tool that will get an image an return the same image after filter.
using Gimp I can select an image go to Filters->Artistics->Cartoon. and get my image cartoonized(or other Artistic option).
Is there a way to do so only with command line, without open the software UI?
If no How can I get the source code including image Filter?

Comment: Did you actually googled? http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/

Comment: yes, didn't find yet filter option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the cartoon filter is a plugin, you'd have to figure out how to call the cartoon plugin.

> (plug-in-cartoon RUN-NONINTERACTIVE image drawable mask-radius pct-black)

Should do the trick if I look at the code that is attached to http://registry.gimp.org/node/6697.

So if you take the last example on http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/ and replace the line with plug-in-unsharp-mask with the above (and rename the batch function), it should probably work...